# How to break out an opemp for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, openmp

I have a very ᴄᴘᴜ intensive *(50 millions calls and over 100 bilions looping phase)* for loop such as :

```
for(int i=0;i<*string;i++){
    if(!check_some_stuff(string+i)) {
        do_some_stuff(i,string-2);
        if(!string)
            break;
       do_yet_other_stuff(string);
    }
}
```

As break statements aren’t allowed for`#pragma omp parallel for odered`I thought I could set`i`to a very large value.

```
for(int i=0;i<*string;i++){
    if(!check_some_stuff(string+i)) {
        do_some_stuff(i,string-2);
        if(!string)
            i=0x7FFFFFFB;
       do_yet_other_stuff(string);
    }
}
```

which perfectly works without openmp. But however when I add

```
#pragma omp parallel for ordered shared(string)
for(int i=0;i<*string;i++){
    if(!check_some_stuff(string+i)) {
        do_some_stuff(i,string-2);
        #pragma omp critical
        if(!string)
            i=0x7FFFFFFB; // it seems the assignment has no effect on the value of i.
       do_yet_other_stuff(*string);
    }
}
```

the value of`i`doesn’t seems to change, so it turns to an infinite loop.

Comment: In the parallel version, changing `i` will have unpredictable results since presumably each iteration of the loops is being handled by a separate thread. Changing the value in one thread will most likely not affect the others.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : it has no effect on any of the threads. But I’m rather looking for an alternative. The contents of the if statement can’t be moved out that if statement.

Comment: Exactly. If you want to break out of the loop properly, you have to be able to signal the main thread somehow. With the `pragma`, `i=0x7FFFFFFB;` becomes a local change that does not affect the outer loop.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : Which I couldn’t found on how to do it with openmp. This is the topic of that question. And it definitely require a full detailed answered for understanding how to.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @MadPhysicist : The version shipped with gcc 5.2.0 *(latest version of the openmp standard)*. `With the pragma, i=0x7FFFFFFB; becomes a local change that does not affect the outer loop`. Are you talking about the critical one ? I put it because I thought it was necessary to prevent other threads from modifying string after`i=0x7FFFFFFB;`, So it’s safe to remove it.

Comment: @user2284570 Do you mean something like [This](http://ideone.com/ptOFiR) ?

Comment: @Michi : same thing, setting`i`inside the middle of the loop of your example don’t seems to have any effect when there’s an opemp #pragma.

Comment: @user2284570 OOPS :), my bad. You right,

Comment: Did a little research (typed your question title into Google as-is), came up with some interesting results from the guys at Intel. Hope the links in my answer help even if the answer itself does not solve your problem completely.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : of course I tried it and fushing`i`don’t change anything.

Comment: `#pragma omp cancel`

Comment: How is `string` modified in the loop? Why did you (try to) preserve order? There are ways for parallelising your loop no problem but having answers to these questions is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
int abort = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for ordered shared(string, abort)
for(int i=0;i<*string;i++)
{
    #pragma omp flush(abort)
    if(!abort)
    {
        if(!check_some_stuff(string+i))
        {
            #pragma omp flush(abort)
            if(!abort) do_some_stuff(i,string-2);
            if(!string) abort = 1;
            #pragma omp flush(abort)
            if(!abort) do_yet_other_stuff(*string);
        }
    }
}
```